# AngularJS newbie error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay so I'm following an AngularJS online beginner course, and wrote my first app :

HTML :

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.name =  'Elliot';
}]);
```

I don't get the desired outcome from this small app, I only get `"Hello {{ name }}!"`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html tag too:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: I missed it! Thanks a lot! :)